# How to programmatically access CosmosDB master key

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm looking for a way to use Azure Python-SDK to access the primary key located on this page in the Azure portal:

[image: azure portal screenshot]

I can access the URI using azure-mgmt-resource library but I'd like to be able to access the keys for all possible CosmosDB resource instances for programmatic management purposes.

Comment: You mean you have many CosmosDB accounts and you want to able to get each one's key with python?

Comment: yes, but we can start with getting they key just for this one instance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [API doc for list keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-cosmosdb/azure.mgmt.cosmosdb.operations.databaseaccountsoperations?view=azure-python#list-keys-resource-group-name--account-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) for the Azure SDK for Python.

You can also [start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-python) for installing and exploring the Azure SDK for Python.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys by

```
 keys = cosmosdb_client.database_accounts.list_keys(Azure.resource_group, database_account_name)
```